# How to install the WSO2 WSAS 5.3.0 Plugins in to the Eclipse Luna version

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-as

I have already installed WSO2 Developer Studio to eclipse-luna,

actually I'm trying to generate the client stubs according to the WSDL.

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/creating-web-service-client-3-steps-using-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pre-installed dev studio pack from the http://wso2.com/more-downloads/developer-studio/. Then refer to WSO2 Dev Studio documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Creating+an+Axis2+Project where it explains how to generate an asix2 client using a WSDL.